# ImageMagick: How to use "Only Shrink Larger Images" ('>' flag) both on windows and unix

Tags: windows, unix, resize, imagemagick, shrink

I found this description on website http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#shrink :

> Only Shrink Larger Images ('>' flag) Another commonly used option is
>   to restrict IM so that it will only shrink images to fit into the size
>   given.   Never enlarge.   This is the '>' resize option.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> convert dragon.gif    -resize 64x64\>  shrink_dragon.gif
> ```
>
> The Only Shrink Flag ('>' flag) is a special character in Window batch
>   scripts and you will need to escape that character, using '^>', or it
>   will not work.

So as I understand this flag ('>') could only work either on windows ^> or unix /> . 
Is there any way to create command that will work both on windows and unix?

I use imagemagick with php, so I've got unix on production webserver, but windows on localhost.

Thank you.

Comment: i was working with im years ago a lot and i remember that i ended up with having a switch `if (win) else` due to the single quotation marks and slashes or back slashes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling ImageMagick from a script, there is probably a built-in function for escaping shell arguments. In Python it's pipes.quote. In PHP it is escape_shell_arg();

Comment: Unfortunatly this isn't solve this problem... because I need to change shell arguments depends on operation system in which my code runs.